# how to conevert firestore sub collection document to pojo class

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pojo

My firestore schema is :

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to get value of product id that was stored in items sub-collection inside order collection, but when try to get orderModel.getItems().getId() it return null.

Also  orderModel.getItems() return null .

My scenario is I want to update product stock count when user place the order so I don't want to make to quires to firestore, so if I can get the id of product from inside the order collection.

Here is my Pojo class :

```
public class PlacedOrderModel {

public PlacedOrderModel() {
}

private String orderid,no_of_items,total_amount,delivery_date,payment_mode,deleiveryname,deliveryemail,deliverymobile_no,deliveryaddress,deliverypincode,status;
private String placed_user_name,Placed_user_email,Placed_user_mobile_no,getPlaced_user_id,expired_date;
private ProductModel items;

public String getExpired_date() {
    return expired_date;
}

public void setExpired_date(String expired_date) {
    this.expired_date = expired_date;
}

public ProductModel getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(ProductModel items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public PlacedOrderModel(String orderid, String no_of_items, String total_amount, String delivery_date, String payment_mode, String deleiveryname, String deliveryemail, String deliverymobile_no, String deliveryaddress, String deliverypincode, String placed_user_name, String getPlaced_user_email, String getPlaced_user_mobile_no, String getPlaced_user_id , String status) {

    this.orderid = orderid;
    this.no_of_items = no_of_items;
    this.total_amount = total_amount;
    this.delivery_date = delivery_date;
    this.payment_mode = payment_mode;
    this.deleiveryname = deleiveryname;
    this.deliveryemail = deliveryemail;
    this.deliverymobile_no = deliverymobile_no;
    this.deliveryaddress = deliveryaddress;
    this.deliverypincode = deliverypincode;
    this.placed_user_name = placed_user_name;
    this.Placed_user_email = getPlaced_user_email;
    this.Placed_user_mobile_no = getPlaced_user_mobile_no;
    this.getPlaced_user_id=getPlaced_user_id;
    this.status=status;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public String getOrderid() {
    return orderid;
}

public void setOrderid(String orderid) {
    this.orderid = orderid;
}

public String getPlaced_user_email() {
    return Placed_user_email;
}

public void setPlaced_user_email(String placed_user_email) {
    Placed_user_email = placed_user_email;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getGetPlaced_user_id() {
    return getPlaced_user_id;
}

public void setGetPlaced_user_id(String getPlaced_user_id) {
    this.getPlaced_user_id = getPlaced_user_id;
}

public String getPlaced_user_mobile_no() {
    return Placed_user_mobile_no;
}

public void setPlaced_user_mobile_no(String placed_user_mobile_no) {
    Placed_user_mobile_no = placed_user_mobile_no;
}

public String getNo_of_items() {
    return no_of_items;
}

public void setNo_of_items(String no_of_items) {
    this.no_of_items = no_of_items;
}

public String getTotal_amount() {
    return total_amount;
}

public void setTotal_amount(String total_amount) {
    this.total_amount = total_amount;
}

public String getDelivery_date() {
    return delivery_date;
}

public void setDelivery_date(String delivery_date) {
    this.delivery_date = delivery_date;
}

public String getPayment_mode() {
    return payment_mode;
}

public void setPayment_mode(String payment_mode) {
    this.payment_mode = payment_mode;
}

public String getDeleiveryname() {
    return deleiveryname;
}

public void setDeleiveryname(String deleiveryname) {
    this.deleiveryname = deleiveryname;
}

public String getDeliveryemail() {
    return deliveryemail;
}

public void setDeliveryemail(String deliveryemail) {
    this.deliveryemail = deliveryemail;
}

public String getDeliverymobile_no() {
    return deliverymobile_no;
}

public void setDeliverymobile_no(String deliverymobile_no) {
    this.deliverymobile_no = deliverymobile_no;
}

public String getDeliveryaddress() {
    return deliveryaddress;
}

public void setDeliveryaddress(String deliveryaddress) {
    this.deliveryaddress = deliveryaddress;
}

public String getDeliverypincode() {
    return deliverypincode;
}

public void setDeliverypincode(String deliverypincode) {
    this.deliverypincode = deliverypincode;
}

public String getPlaced_user_name() {
    return placed_user_name;
}

public void setPlaced_user_name(String placed_user_name) {
    this.placed_user_name = placed_user_name;
}
```

And product pojo class :

```
public class ProductModel implements Serializable, Parcelable {

  private String title , image , desc ,userEmail ,userMobile ,expireDate     ,id;
private int price  ,no_of_items ,currentStock , initStock;


private boolean isExpired;
public ProductModel(String id , String title, int price, String desc ,    String image, int no_of_items, String userEmail , String userMobile, String    expireDate, int currentStock , int initStock) {
    this.id=id;
    this.title = title;
    this.price=price;
    this.desc=desc;
    this.image = image;
    this.no_of_items=no_of_items;
    this.userEmail=userEmail;
    this.userMobile=userMobile;
    this.expireDate=expireDate;
    this.currentStock=currentStock;
    this.initStock=initStock;

}

public int getCurrentStock() {
    return currentStock;
}

public void setCurrentStock(int currentStock) {
    this.currentStock = currentStock;
}

public int getInitStock() {
    return initStock;
}

public void setInitStock(int initStock) {
    this.initStock = initStock;
}

public ProductModel() {



}

public boolean getExpireStatus(){
    String valid_until = getExpireDate();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date strDate = null;
    try {
        strDate = sdf.parse(valid_until);
    } catch (SafeParcelReader.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (new Date().after(strDate)) {

        isExpired = true;
    }
    else{
        isExpired = false;

    }
    return isExpired;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public int getNo_of_items() {
    return no_of_items;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String getExpireDate() {
    return this.expireDate;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(image);
    dest.writeString(desc);
    dest.writeString(userEmail);
    dest.writeString(userMobile);
    dest.writeString(id);
    dest.writeInt(no_of_items);
    dest.writeInt(price);
    dest.writeString(expireDate);
    dest.writeInt(currentStock);
    dest.writeInt(initStock);

}



public static final Parcelable.Creator<ProductModel> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<ProductModel>() {
    public ProductModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ProductModel(in);
    }

    public ProductModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ProductModel[size];
    }
};

private ProductModel(Parcel in) {
    title = in.readString();
    image = in.readString();
    desc = in.readString();
    userEmail = in.readString();
    userMobile = in.readString();
    id = in.readString();
    no_of_items = in.readInt();
    price = in.readInt();
    expireDate = in.readString();
    currentStock = in.readInt();
    initStock = in.readInt();

}
```

Comment: You did not post code on how you are retrieving the data.
From the pictures, you can see that you are trying to fetch data from orphaned collections. The italics ids under the `order` collections mean that those documents does not exists. Maybe you want to initialize the orders documents before trying to fetch the items.
It would be better if you post the code you use to fetch the items.

Comment: Please add the code where you are getting `null`?